# How do I make bootstrap carousel full width and responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How would I make my Bootstrap carousel full width and responsive with HTML and CSS?

Currently it only fill the 12 columns and in the mobile version it's difficult to read the slides.

**The Code (http://www.bootply.com/6BQnZtGFlz):**

```css
.content-section-b {
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-color: #3C5A78;
}
.section-heading {
  color: #ffffff;
}
h2 {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #3C5A78;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 0 0 16px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-section-b">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h2 class="section-heading">What Other Clients Are Saying</h2>
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
          <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          </ol>
          
          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/test_01_02.png" alt="Transit Distrcit and City Purchasing">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/03_04.png" alt="Fire District and County Procurement">
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</div>
<!-- /.content-section-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Just removed the container. Here is the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Czechhinzur/q20gtLsw/

```
<div class="content-section-b">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">...
```